# SeleniumGrid: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unable to parse remote response: <html> <head> <title>

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, remotewebdriver

I'm trying to write test cases using selenium. I wrote this code. And i got this error

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unable to parse remote response:

but I don't understand what is wrong

```html
    public static WebDriver driver=null;
    ATUTestRecorder recorder;
        
    @Parameters({"browsername"})
    @BeforeTest
    public void setUpBrowser(String browsername) throws ATUTestRecorderException, MalformedURLException
    {
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss").format(new Date());
        recorder = new ATUTestRecorder("./ScreenRecorder/","Test_"+timeStamp+".mp4",false);
        DesiredCapabilities cap =null;

        if(driver==null)
        {
            if(browsername.equalsIgnoreCase("Firefox"))
            {
                // Set the path for geckodriver.exe
                //System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "./Drivers/geckodriver.exe");
                //WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();
                cap = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
                cap.setBrowserName("firefox");
                cap.setPlatform(Platform.ANY);

                driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"),cap);
            }           
            // If the browser is Chrome
            else if(browsername.equalsIgnoreCase("Chrome"))
            {
                // Set the path for chromedriver.exe
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./Drivers/chromedriver.exe");
                //WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
                cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
                cap.setBrowserName("chrome");
                cap.setPlatform(Platform.ANY);
                System.out.println(driver);

                driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"),cap);
            }
            // If the browser is IE
            else if(browsername.equalsIgnoreCase("IE"))
            {
                // Set the path for IEdriver.exe
                //System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "./Drivers/IEDriverServer.exe");
                //WebDriverManager.iedriver().setup();
                cap = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
                cap.setBrowserName("internetExplorer");
                cap.setPlatform(Platform.ANY);
                
                driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"),cap);
            }
            
            driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.get(DataConfig.baseURL);

        }
        recorder.start();   
    }
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: please match chrome and chromedriver version and check your url is right. and also add screenshot and error trace

Answer (score 0):

Remove `/wd/hub` from your driver URL.

See example at https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/remote_webdriver/

Comment: i tried it. but then it will give another error  - "org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-DGNP064', ip: '10.0.0.149', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '16'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
"

Answer (score 0):

Your Selenium URL should be:

http://localhost:4444/wd/hub

also please update the Webdrivermanager dependency to the latest, I used 5.4.0 it worked.